# How do I pass the method of payment from CF CiviCRM to CiviCRM?

Tags: civicontribute, payment-processor, paylater, caldera-forms

I'm building a contribution form in Caldera and using the CF CiviCRM contribution processor. I can't figure out how to enable options for both the online payment gateway and the "pay later" for users needing to write checks. Also, can I get the CiviCRM invoice to generate from this form, or do I need to generate new invoices?

Do I need separate contribution processors and conditions for each payment scenario? How do I pass the pay later back to CiviCRM?

Since a manager is processing re-certifications for multiple contacts, should I be using the order or contribution processor? Sorry for all the questions, but I am very confused right now.